# Summing odd numbers

Tags: summation

$$1+3+5+7+ \cdots + (2n-1) = \, ??$$  Can you help me?

Comment: What have you tired? What are the first few values? What do you conjecture after seeing those first few values?

Comment: Write your sum as $2(1+2+\cdots+n)-n$. Do you know how to compute the sum in the parentheses?

Comment: I want to underline the importance of @ThomasAndrews' answer. Whenever you encounter something like this in mathematics that you don't yet understand, do what every good scientist (including mathematicians!!) do: **experiment**. See what the value is for different values of $n$. The posts below show you how to prove the solution. But the most important insight is figuring out the hypothesis of the answer to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

$$s=1+3+5+7+9+...+(2n-1)\\s=(2n-1)+(2n-3)+...+5+3+1$$ no look to sum of them $$s+s=(1+(2n-1))+(3+(2n-3)+(5+(2n-5))+...+((2n-3)+3)+((2n-1)+1)\\2s=(2n)+(2n)+(2n)+...+(2n)\\$$ there is $n$ terms $$ 2s=n(2n)\\2s=2n^2\\s=n^2$$[image]

Comment: You want $2s=n(2n)$, but typo-ed $2s+n(2n)$

Answer (score 3):

Meditate carefully on [this image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_without_words#/media/File:Proofwithoutwords.svg):

[image]

Comment: I rolled back the edit made by another user to this post because it (a) was confusing with its use of minus signs but more importantly (b) materially changed someone else's answer, which is generally considered bad form here on Math SE.

Comment: Thanks. Given the lack of effort shown in the question, I was trying to be at least a little cryptic.

Answer (score 1):

You want $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} (2k-1) = 2\sum_{k=1}^n k - \sum_{k=1}^n 1 = 2\cdot \frac{1}{2}n(n+1) - n$$

This simplifies nicely to $$\bbox[10px, border: blue solid 1px]{\sum_{k=1}^{n} (2k-1) = n^2.}$$